# Aggregating numerous polygons into one with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, union, aggregation

I have this PostGIS query which aggregates many polygons according to a variable ("region"):

```sql
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON((ST_Collect(polygons)),3) as geom
FROM table
GROUP BY region;
```

The `ST_Collect()` returns a collection of polygons as it should but, since my goal in aggregating polygons is to reduce the number of vertices, how can I turn this collection of MultiPolygons into a single multi polygon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `st_union()` instead of `st_collect()`

The [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) says

> ST_Collect and ST_Union are often interchangeable. ST_Union is in
>   general orders of magnitude slower than ST_Collect because it tries to
>   dissolve boundaries and reorder geometries to ensure that a
>   constructed Multi* doesn't have intersecting regions.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `ST_Union`; the function will attempt to dissolve the aggregated geometries:

```
SELECT ST_Union(<polygons>) AS geom
FROM   <table>
GROUP BY
       region
;
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Although, I was having ERROR:  GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point... and had to specify "WHERE ST_isValid(polygons)", is this a good work around?

Comment: +1 for grouping by region

Comment: @LucienS. Yes. You can try `SELECT ST_Union(ST_MakeValid(<polygons>))) ... WHERE ST_IsValid(ST_MakeValid(<polygons>));` (leave out the `WHERE` filter first to see if you get them all fixed!)